# How to send Firebase message to specific application in project?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications

I have a doubt based on firebase. It allows to add multiple application for a single project. I have added App1, App2 and App3. How can I send a  notification to App1 alone? Server key is the same for those 3 apps.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In the Notifications panel in the Firebase Console, you can send a notification message to a specific app. But there is no support for such targeting in the Firebase Cloud Messaging API.

You can easily emulate the behavior though, by defining a specific property for each of your apps: `/topics/apps-app1`, `/topics/apps-app2`, etc. Then [have each app subscribe to its own topic](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/topic-messaging#subscribe_the_client_app_to_a_topic) and you can target the users of each app with a single FCM server key.

Comment: Frank van Puffelen generally i send notification it receives all applications right? What is the use to add multiple apps in single project? is multiple app only for different build environment?

Comment: FCM messages can be targeted to a specific device (or list of specific devices), a device group, or a topic. I have projects with many apps, each of them doing something unrelated. If I'd want to send messages to the users of a specific app, I'd make a topic mapping as I described in my answer.